# can't invoke paint

Tags: c#, custom-controls, paint, onpaint

I created my own control and overwritten the onpaint event,
the problem is that the paint event stopped working

Any ideas why? And how to restore it?

Comment: Define "stops working" - what happens (or doesn't), and in what scenario?

Comment: this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(myControl_Paint);

Comment: the event 'myControl_Paint' never raised

Comment: Still not enough code. Did you override OnPaint or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a telepathic guess here:

You forgot to call `base.OnPaint(...)` inside your override. Meaning that the base functionality is no longer invoked.

Comment: Psychic debugging; always fun :)

Comment: didn't forgot, I did it on purpose, is this the only way to bring back the paint event?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the control is obscured. I had a similar problem, and the problem was that the form in the Designer view was bigger than the actual form when the application was run. My custom control had anchors on all sides, and when the main form was reduced in size, the custom control went to zero size (actually negative I guess).

In this mode, the OnPaint override nor a delegate assigned to the Paint event is not called at all.

Maximize your form and make sure that you didn't accidentally reduce the size to zero!